# Ajax error in datatables server-side processing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using [datatable server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side) to display large data from database.

Here is my page

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Datatable</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="table-responsive">
   <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>CustomerName</th>
                <th>OrderNumber</th>
                <th>OrderDate</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
   </div>

 </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
     url:"fetchData.php",
     type:"POST" }
    } );
 });
</script>
```

And here is my fetchData.php

```
<?php   
include("connection.php");

 $querySelect= "SELECT Country, CustomerName, OrderNumber, OrderDate, Address, Qty";

 $queryWhere = " FROM OrdersTable WHERE ShipDate > '2018-04-01'";

if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
 $queryWhere .= '
 AND ( Country LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
 OR CustomerName LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
 OR OrderNumber LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
 OR OrderDate LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
 OR Address LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
 OR Qty LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ) 
 ';
}

if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
 $queryWhere .= 'ORDER BY '.$columns[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' 
 ';
}

$res = $dbDB->query('SELECT COUNT(*)' .$queryWhere);
$number_filter_row = $res->fetchColumn();

$result = $dbDB->query($querySelect . $queryWhere);
$data = array();

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $sub_array = array();
  $sub_array[] = $row["Country"];
  $sub_array[] = $row["CustomerName"];
  $sub_array[] = $row["OrderNumber"];
  $sub_array[] = $row["OrderDate"];
  $sub_array[] = $row["Address"];
  $sub_array[] = $row["Qty"];
  $data[] = $sub_array;
}

$r = $dbDB->query("SELECT COUNT(*)FROM OrdersTable WHERE ShipDate > '2018-04-01'");
$get_all_data = $r->fetchColumn();

$output = array(
 "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
 "recordsTotal"  =>  $get_all_data,
 "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
 "data"    => $data
);

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

When I load my page I receive this error 
`DataTables warning: table id=example - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7`

and in my console i get this `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

When I load just fetchData.php it works fine I can see the expected data. Based on the previous threads I was checking it's an error in the server request. Any ideas please how to fix this error ? Thank you.

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` on top of your php page and from developer console (within firefox or chrome or similar browser) look at the net tab to see what your ajax returns.

Comment: @Cemal  Yes I can see in the response the data I want

Comment: if the result you're looking at isn't responding with 500, you're looking at somewhere wrong.